# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^n\sin\frac{1}{3^nz}$

Tags: complex-analysis, absolute-convergence

The problem is:
prove $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^n\sin\frac{1}{3^nz}$ converges absolutely for all $z\neq 0$, but does not converge uniformly near $z=0$.

*Proof*:
for all $z\neq 0$
$$\left|2^n\sin\frac{1}{3^nz}-2^n\frac{1}{3^nz}\right|
= \left|
2^n\left(
    -\frac{(\frac{1}{3^nz})^3}{3!}+\frac{(\frac{1}{3^nz})^5}{5!}\dots
\right)
\right|, \ \ \ \ (1)$$

$\exists~ N$ such that when n>N, $\frac{1/z}{3^n}<1$, so that (1) is less than
$$\left|
2^n\left(
    \frac{|\frac{1}{3^nz}|^3}{3!}+\frac{|\frac{1}{3^nz}|^5}{5!}\dots
\right)
\right|
<\left|
\frac{2^n}{3^nz}\left(
    \frac{|\frac{1}{3^nz}|^2}{1-|\frac{1}{3^nz}|^2}
\right)
\right|
<\frac{2^n}{3^n}\left|
\frac{1}{z}\left(
    \frac{|\frac{1}{3^nz}|^2}{1-|\frac{1}{3^nz}|^2}
\right)
\right|,
$$

$\forall~ \epsilon, \exists~ N_1>-\log(\epsilon^{1/2} z^{3/2})$, such that when $n>N_2=\max\{N, N_1\}$, $|\frac{1}{z}||\frac{1}{3^nz}|^2<\epsilon$, and so (1) is less $\frac{2^n}{3^n}\epsilon$.

Therefore, we have $N_2(\epsilon)$ satisfying that $\forall~ p,$
$$\left|\sum_{n=N_2}^{N_2+p} 2^n\sin\frac{1}{3^nz}-\sum_{n=N_2}^{N_2+p} 2^n\frac{1}{3^nz}\right|
<\sum_{n=N_2}^{N_2+p} \left|2^n\sin\frac{1}{3^nz}-2^n\frac{1}{3^nz}\right|\ \ \ \ (2)\\
<\sum_{n=N_2}^{N_2+p}\frac{2^n}{3^n}\epsilon
\leq 2\epsilon,
$$

and so $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^n\sin\frac{1}{3^nz}$ converges absolutely. (A step seems to be missing. One should, instead of $\sum_{n=N_2}^{N_2+p}\frac{2^n}{3^n}$, use something like 2/z (plus a constant), which is the limit of the former.)$\blacksquare$

A possibly trivial *question* is whether it is proper to prove this way: given n sufficiently large, $u_n<f(n)\epsilon$ (different from that $u_n<\epsilon$, or that $u_n/f(n)<\epsilon$ and so $u_n<f(n)\epsilon$).

---

There are other questions that I may post somewhere else.

---

The following is a proof that the series doesn't converge uniformly. It's unnecessarily for answering my *questions*, but I put it here for completeness of proof.

*Proof*:

However large $N_2$, we can find $n_0$>$N_2$ and $z=\frac{2}{\pi 3^{n_0}}$ such that $2^{n_0}\sin\frac{1}{3^{n_0}z}=2^{n_0}$, and so (say the limit function is $f(z)=\frac{2}{z}+C$, where $C$ is a constant; I suddenly realize C seems also to be a function of z, that could cause some issues),

$$\left|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2^n\sin\frac{1}{3^nz}-f(z)\right|
>\left|\sum_{n=N_2}^{N_2+p} 2^n\sin\frac{1}{3^nz}-\sum_{n=N_2}^{N_2+p} 2^n\frac{1}{3^nz}-C\right|>|2^{n_0}-\frac{2}{z}-C|>\epsilon.$$

Comment: The terms of sine will tend towards zero so terms of the sequence converge towards (2/3)^n

Comment: I guess for extremely small z, it will not tend to 0? (Since n and z are independent of each other, so when 3^n goes large, 1/z may go larger) Well, I rethink about it, that's not an issue for proving absolute convergence. What confuses me is that we need to sum up difference between $2^n\sin(1/3^nz)$ and $(2^n/3^nz)$ for each n, and the resulted difference may not be arbitrarily small.

Comment: $\sin(x)\approx x$ is an upper bound and zero is a lower bound

Answer (score 1):

One easily proves the result even uniformly for $z \in K$ compact that doesn't contain $0$ since for all such there is $A=A_K >0, |z| \ge A, z \in K$; then pick $n_K, (8/9)^n \le A$ or equivalently $(2/3)^n \le A(3/4)^n, n \ge n_K$ and use that for $|w| \le 1/2, |\sin w| \le C|w|$ which can be easily seen since $|\sin w /w|$ is bounded and continuos there;

then for $n \ge n_K, z \in K,  |3^nz| \ge A3^n \ge 2$ since $A(9/8)^n \ge 1$ by our choice of $n_K$, hence $|\sin (1/(3^nz)| \le C/|3^nz|$ or $2^n|\sin (1/(3^nz)| \le C(3/4)^n$ again by our choice of $n_K$

So one has uniformly in $z \in K$ that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |2^n\sin\frac{1}{3^nz}| \le f_K(z)+ \sum_{n \ge n_K}C(3/4)^n$ where $f_K$ is the finite sum of the absolute values of the terms from $1$ ro $n_K-1$ so it is a fixed (for $K$ fixed) continuos function on $K$, so in particularly the OP series converges absolutely and uniformly on $K$

For part $2$ and $z=1/3^N$ the $N$ term of the series is $2^N/\sin 1$ so is unbounded with $N$ which shows that the partial series cannot be uniformly bounded for the sequence $z_N \to 0$, so in particular, they cannot converge uniformly

Comment: So here we use a intermediary series $\sum (3/4)^n$ instead of using directly $\sum (2/3)^n$ which seems ‘safer’. By comparison one term by one we get the absolute convergence. [For non-uniform convergence, we can possibly bypass the issue of C as function of z by setting the domain to be closed and excluding 0. Well I notice this understanding is incorrect.]

Comment: it happens that $(3/4)^n$ works here - any $a^n, 2/3<a<1$ can be used - but any absolutely convergent series which majorizes term by term the given series from $n \ge n_K$ for a compact $K$ works in general and is usually the way these things are done (the series could depend on the compact set of course); similarly uniform convergence implies boundness (and in this case analytic continuation) at the singularity and here this is manifestly not the case

Answer (score 0):

Further to my comment, we can use that $\sin(x)\to x$ for $x\to0$ and look at the ratio of terms:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^{n+1}\times z\times3^n}{2^n\times z\times 3^{n+1}}=\frac 23<1$$
As you mentioned the problem is as $z\to0$, $\sin\left(\frac 1{3^nz}\right)\not\to0$